# StackDriver process monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am completely new to Google StackDriver and getting stuck with how to monitor the processes. My scenario is I want to watch some particular process (node and one simple application) and if those processes overuse some resource in the system, it should trigger the alert notification to my email.

According to the documentation from Google, I can set the alert policy based on the process name in the `Add Process Health Condition`. However, only simple operation like counting the number of the processes can be triggered according to the UI.

[image]

How could I configure the stack driver based on the requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

You can install Stackdriver Monitoring Agent on your system and configure the agent to monitor custom metrics or metrics for third-party applications. The steps to install and configure stackdrvier agent are documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/). The complete list of supported metrics can be found on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics#agent).